# How may I determine if `mod_mime_magic` is loaded for `httpd`?

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd

I cannot tell if the `mod_mime_magic` httpd module is loaded or being used. When I run `httpd -l` and `httpd -M` it doesn't show up in the lists, but I am not convinced it's not loaded. The package manager used to install it adds a file called `magic` in /etc/httpd/conf, which is the default file location corresponding to the `MimeMagicFile` directive for `mod_mime_magic`.

`LoadModule mod_mime_magic` shows up as a line in the file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf`. The Fedora 28 web server docs seems to indicate that the configuration files in `conf.modules.d` load `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, but it's not clear if this is the default is active on installation or if it must be configured to load things from `conf.modules.d` by choice.

For reference:

- [Documentation for `mod_mime_magic`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime_magic.html)
- [Fedora 28 Apache HTTP Server
  docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f28/system-administrators-guide/servers/Web_Servers/#s1-The_Apache_HTTP_Server)

Comment: How can I take this question off hold? I think I improved the wording.

Comment: You can't, there is a vote. 2 voted to reopen until now, and 2 to leave closed. I am trying to reopen it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. If there is anything I can do to clarify, or improve the question, please let me know!

Comment: Don't have a hostage syndrom, not you were bad, the site is overmoderated. It is a structural error in the whole SE.

Comment: Unfortunately, also a third "leave closed" vote arrived, thus the vote resulted a "leave closed" decision. The next step: edit your post. Not only its title, but also its body! Make more clear, what exactly you want to know about this. "mod_mime_magic" is not a "magic file", it is an apache module. If you want to know, if it is used for anything, then the answer is: YES. It decides from statically served files their mime type. But wtf is this version control thing et al? Are you version controlling your /etc? If you now edit your post, a new reopen vote will be started, where the people

Comment: already voted (incl. me, but also the "leave closed" voters) can't vote again, and in this new vote you already need to collect 3 new "reopen" votes. But be convincing! On my second read, also I see your post already unclear.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tips. I edited again, and I think it's much more clear than before. For what it's worth, I wasn't implying that the file `/etc/httpd/conf/magic` was magic in the magical sense. I was simply referring to it as `magic` because that's the literal filename.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the size of your estate, the consistency of the environment, any automation tools...

For example, a large centralised team may use tools such as `ansible` or `puppet` to perform "configuration management".

Small teams where every server is uniquely configured may want to use a version control system.

Other teams must just rely on backups.

There's no one-size-fits-all solution.